# Proof that an involutory (ie: $A^2 = I$) $n*n$ matrix has determinant of 1 or -1

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am going over a linear algebra book and am having trouble with this question. For context, the book hasn't covered eigenvalues (if that's relevant) but did cover basis and dimension already. He's what I was thinking:

$A^2 = I$ implies that either $A = I^{0.5}$ or $A = -I^{0.5}$

In the first case, $det(A) = 1$. And in the second case $det(A) = -1$. Those are the two cases.

However, even if the above steps are correct, I am not necessarily sure how to prove the second case, that $det[-\sqrt(I)] = -1$

Comment: Have you proved the multiplication theorem? That $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$

Comment: Ah! Yes, we did. I just saw an answer below which used this. But thank you for the tip.

Comment: It's also not too hard to prove a "structure theorem": if $W_1 = \{ x \in F^n : A x = x \}$ and $W_{-1} = \{ x \in F^n : A x = -x \}$, then $F^n = W_1 \oplus W_{-1}$.  Then it's fairly easy to show $\det(A) = (-1)^{\dim(W_{-1})}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A^{2}=I$ hence $\det(A^{2})=\det(I)$, so $\det(A)\det(A)=1$ so $\det(A)^{2}=1$ and hence $\det(A)=1$ or $\det(A)=-1$

Comment: Just for the record, `$\det$` will print as $\det,$ and is usually preferred to $det$.

Comment: edited... thanks!